# time for navigation in /move_base trajectory planner

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a problem where i will have a set of goals for the robot and i have to choose the one which takes less time. Though move_base does the same, this time details is important for my probabilistic logic. So is there a way to compute the estimated time for the navigation to a particular goal. Is there a package that does this or can i tweak somewhere to get this information. I make use of the /move_base package inside the navigation stack as of now. Any pointers and suggestions here is appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29184/time-for-navigation-in-/move_base-trajectory-planner/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indirectly there is. move_base provides a service:

~make_plan (nav_msgs/GetPlan)

This doesn't give you time, but a path length that given an assumed speed gives you a time estimate.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-03-06**:
Thanks alot :)